# How to update the user data with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database

I'm making a learning management system for the students. On the signup page I'm asking the student to tell me how many number of courses you're enrolling in this semester so that according to that i give him the number of list of teachers to save to his subject.

The below jquery code is running okay and updating the values when the student wants to select a subject. But i need something more accurate. This code only shows the number of lists that are pre written in it. I want to make it dynamic that if the student selects taking '2' courses then only two of these list items should show up there. Any body can help?

> The jquery and html code is

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">Semester 1</option>
<option value="2">Semester 2</option>
<option value="3">Semester 3</option>
<option value="4">Semester 4</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">name of Subject 1 from semester 1</option>
<option value="1">name of Subject 2 from semester 1</option>
<option value="1">name of Subject 3 from semester 1</option>
<option value="2">name of Subject 1 from semester 2</option>
<option value="2">name of Subject 2 from semester 2</option>
<option value="2">name of Subject 2 from semester 2</option>
<option value="3">name of Subject 1 from semester 3</option>
<option value="3">name of Subject 1 from semester 3</option>
<option value="4">name of Subject 1 from semester 4<option>
</select>
```

> and

```
$("#select1").change(function() {  if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    }  var id = $(this).val(); var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']'); $('#select2').html(options); });
```

For speedy checking you can see the running code here on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aroshkhan/nye5mo9h/2/)**

Comment: any reason why not using example php/mysql database to solve this?

Comment: do you know how to make such a logic or an algorithm using mysql/php ?